# Magento 2.2 installation on Windows OS

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Can't we install or run the Magento 2.2 on our Windows machine with WAMP or XAMPP?

Please provide some details, as I have gone through the official documentation of Magento where they only mentioned about the Linux OS.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install-flow-diagram.html

Thanks

Comment: rajnikant-das please check https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-localhost/

Answer (score 1):

You can install that in windows machine.

Here is my php configuration that i m using for my **magento version 2.2.2**

> Apache 2.4.27
>
> PHP 7.1.9 Mysql
>
> 5.7.19
>
> Wamp 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing Magento on WAMP or XAMPP you are essentially installing it on Linux, since those are Linux containers even if you are using a Windows machine.

What specific step of the process are you having trouble with?

Answer (score -1):

Mangeto 2.2 can't run in windows system, if will show blank screen after the **setup:di:compile**.